# THE SQL CREATE STATEMENT HAS EXCUTES WITH ERROR

Tags: java, mysql

Can any one help identify where the problem is with this sql create statement. Am trying to excute using JDBC driver but it returns an error:com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`asms`.`customerAccount` (  `trn_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO' at line 1.
 Am using mysql db

```
      String createAccount = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `asms`.`customerAccount`"
            + "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`asms`.`customerAccount` ( "
            + " `trn_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, "
            + " `trn_date` DATE NOT NULL, "
            + " `narration` VARCHAR(200) NULL, "
            + " `value_date` VARCHAR(50) NULL, "
            + " `debit` DOUBLE NULL,  `credit` DOUBLE NULL,"
            + "  `ledger_balance` DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT 0.0, "
            + " `credit_account_no` VARCHAR(50) NULL, "
            + " `customerAccountcol` VARCHAR(100)NULL, "
            + " `tra_ref_number` VARCHAR(50) NULL, "
            + " `trn_type` VARCHAR(10) NULL, "
            + " `action_type` VARCHAR(10) NULL,  "
            + "`approve_insu_funds` VARCHAR(10) NULL,"
            + "  PRIMARY KEY (`trn_id`), "
            + " UNIQUE INDEX `debit_UNIQUE` (`debit` ASC),"
            + "  UNIQUE INDEX `credit_UNIQUE` (`credit` ASC),"
            + "  UNIQUE INDEX `ledger_balance_UNIQUE` (`ledger_balance` ASC))ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 00001";
```

Comment: I guess you cannot execute two DML statements at the same JDBC statement. `DROP TABLE` and `CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Probably because there's no DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS statement in SQL. Without any separator, this is one big statement (with invalid syntax).

Comment: That's right, but isn't there a way these statements can be run in one statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be 2 queries, 1st one drops the table, 2nd one creates the new one

1st drop the table if exists

```
String dropTableQuery= "DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS `asms`.`customerAccount`";
//execute the query now
```

then do the create query

```
String createAccount ="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`asms`.`customerAccount` ( "
        + " `trn_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, "
        + " `trn_date` DATE NOT NULL, "
        + " `narration` VARCHAR(200) NULL, "
        + " `value_date` VARCHAR(50) NULL, "
        + " `debit` DOUBLE NULL,  `credit` DOUBLE NULL,"
        + "  `ledger_balance` DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT 0.0, "
        + " `credit_account_no` VARCHAR(50) NULL, "
        + " `customerAccountcol` VARCHAR(100)NULL, "
        + " `tra_ref_number` VARCHAR(50) NULL, "
        + " `trn_type` VARCHAR(10) NULL, "
        + " `action_type` VARCHAR(10) NULL,  "
        + "`approve_insu_funds` VARCHAR(10) NULL,"
        + "  PRIMARY KEY (`trn_id`), "
        + " UNIQUE INDEX `debit_UNIQUE` (`debit` ASC),"
        + "  UNIQUE INDEX `credit_UNIQUE` (`credit` ASC),"
        + "  UNIQUE INDEX `ledger_balance_UNIQUE` (`ledger_balance` ASC))ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 00001";
```

//and ofc. execute the query

Comment: How would you edit my string to meet my intended end?